# Radio buttons in widget not saving

Tags: widgets

I am struggling with a common issue that many people appear to have encountered over the years. In creating a widget I need a series of radio buttons. Using the code below I can create and show the radio buttons, yet it does not seem to save the value to the database, showing all as unchecked when I hit the save button and nothing is returned on the widget front end.

I believe it is how the radio buttons themselves are declared but do struggle with this level of coding. Is it to do with the **$this->get_field_id('')** tags not properly declared? I have tried many different permutations but with no luck.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

```
// 1
function Widget_case_study() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Radio buttons', 'radio_buttons') );
}

// 2
function form($instance) {
$radio_buttons = esc_attr($instance['radio_buttons']);

    ?>
   <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text_area'); ?>">
        <?php echo('Radio buttons'); ?>
    </label><br>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_option_1'); ?>">
        <?php _e('Option 1:'.$radio_buttons); ?>
        <input class="" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_option_1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_buttons'); ?>" type="radio" value="radio_option_1" <?php if($radio_buttons === 'radio_option_1'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
    </label><br>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_option_2'); ?>">
        <?php _e('Option 2:'.$radio_buttons); ?>
        <input class="" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_option_2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_buttons'); ?>" type="radio" value="radio_option_2" <?php if($radio_option_1 === 'radio_option_2'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
    </label>
    </p>
    <?php 
}

// 3
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
$instance = $old_instance;
$instance['radio_buttons'] = strip_tags($new_instance['radio_buttons']);
    return $instance;
}

// 4
function widget($args, $instance) { 
    extract( $args );
    $radio_buttons = $instance['radio_buttons'];
?>
        <?php echo $before_widget; ?>
    <p>Radio button value/status: <?php echo $radio_buttons; ?></p>
        <?php echo $after_widget; ?>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Got it, it turns out...

1. The label for each radio button must be the field id / variable, in my example is 'radio_buttons'
2. The IF statement for each radio button must refer to this same ID - **$radio_buttons === 'radio_option_1'** & **$radio_buttons === 'radio_option_2'**

My new code which works is...

```
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text_area'); ?>">
        <?php echo('Radio buttons'); ?>
    </label><br>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_buttons'); ?>">
        <?php _e('Option 1:'); ?>
        <input class="" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_option_1'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('radio_buttons'); ?>" type="radio" value="radio_option_1" <?php if($radio_buttons === 'radio_option_1'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
    </label><br>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_buttons'); ?>">
        <?php _e('Option 2:'); ?>
        <input class="" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('radio_option_2'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('radio_buttons'); ?>" type="radio" value="radio_option_2" <?php if($radio_buttons === 'radio_option_2'){ echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> />
    </label>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggles with javascript issue, **wrong checked gets checked**, make shure the HTML not have empty `checked=""` attributes. Only add the attribute on selected radio button.

This code works for a widget with radio-buttons **without if-statements:**

```
function form( $instance ) {

    /* Option carrier is 'ecw_column' */
    $ecw_column = isset( $instance['ecw_column'] ) ? $instance['ecw_column'] : 'ecw_column_none';

    echo '<p>';

    $value = 'ecw_column_1';

    echo '<input value="'. $value .'" class="widefat" id="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'" name="'. $this->get_field_name('ecw_column') .'" type="radio"'. ($ecw_column == $value ? ' checked="checked"' : '') .' />';
    echo '<label for="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'">'. __('Column start') .'</label>';
    echo '<br/>';

    $value = 'ecw_column_2';

    echo '<input value="'. $value .'" class="widefat" id="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'" name="'. $this->get_field_name('ecw_column') .'" type="radio"'. ($ecw_column == $value ? ' checked="checked"' : '') .' />';
    echo '<label for="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'">'. __('Breakpoint') .'</label>';
    echo '<br/>';

    $value = 'ecw_column_3';

    echo '<input value="'. $value .'" class="widefat" id="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'" name="'. $this->get_field_name('ecw_column') .'" type="radio"'. ($ecw_column == $value ? ' checked="checked"' : '') .' />';
    echo '<label for="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'">'. __('Column end') .'</label>';
    echo '<br/>';

    /* Default value */
    $value = 'ecw_column_none';

    echo '<input value="'. $value .'" class="widefat" id="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'" name="'. $this->get_field_name('ecw_column') .'" type="radio"'. ($ecw_column == $value ? ' checked="checked"' : '') .' />';
    echo '<label for="'. $this->get_field_id($value) .'">'. __('Current') .'</label>';

    echo '</p>';
}
```